# Нет новых стикеров в Инстаграм Instagram

Tags: php, android, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

Нет новых стикеров (вопросы, таймер, опрос, музыка) в Instagram.

Что делать, как их получить? Или как связаться с Инстаграм!?

Приложение обновленное. Много чего перепробовал, не появляются.

А так же пробовал сделать это через [instagram-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) из предложенных примеров на сайте работает только сo стикерами "Poll"

На остальных постить пустую историю с картинкой.

[image: скриншот]

Использую код:

```
$profilePicUrl = $ig->account->getCurrentUser()->getUser()->getProfilePicUrl();
// Now create the metadata array:
$metadata = [
    'story_questions' => [
        // Note that you can only do one story question in this array.
        [
            'x'                     => 0.5, // Range: 0.0 - 1.0. Note that x = 0.5 and y = 0.5 is center of screen.
            'y'                     => 0.5004223, // Also note that X/Y is setting the position of the CENTER of the clickable area.
            'z'                     => 0, // Don't change this value.
            'width'                 => 0.63118356, // Clickable area size, as percentage of image size: 0.0 - 1.0
            'height'                => 0.22212838, // ...
            'rotation'              => 0.0,
            'viewer_can_interact'   => false, // Don't change this value.
            'background_color'      => '#ffffff',
            'profile_pic_url'       => $profilePicUrl, // Must be the profile pic url of the account you are posting from!
            'question_type'         => 'text', // Don't change this value.
            'question'              => 'What do you want to see in the API?', // Story question.
            'text_color'            => '#000000',
            'is_sticker'            => true, // Don't change this value.
        ],
    ],
];
```

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть картинка но без вопроса.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию

Comment: А если я спрошу почему не работают вопросы через Instagram-api ?

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы на него могли ответить программисты, а не пользователи Инстаграмма)

Comment: @Jarvis_J попробуете ответить теперь?)